# Performance between tls with hpkp

Tags: security, ssl, https, tls1.2

I'm looking for a performance comparison between a connection to one server with "classic" tls (no hpkp enabled) and another one with tls with hpkp enabled.
Where I can find these information or where can I find steps or a guide to follow?

Any help would be highly appreceated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HPKP only consists of an additional check which compares the fingerprint of the public key in the certificate against a known value. This is a very cheap operation compared to all the other operations which need also to be done on a full TLS handshake, like:

- validating the certificate chain is more expensive than checking the fingerprint only
- key exchange is way more expensive then validating the certificate chain
- and the costs of communication are usually way higher unless you have a low-latency connection or a very slow CPU

In summary: you will probably not be able to measure any performance impact caused by HPKP.